# For loop with weird parameters

Tags: for-loop, parameters

What do you call a for loop like this? I really want to learn more about it, but I can't seek any information on it. I know : is short for an if statement.

```
for (int a : int b) { statement; }
```

Comment: Which programming language ?

Comment: if you add a tag with the language you are using there is a slim chance your question won't be put on hold

Comment: Most likely the OP does not know what language this is. That is why the question exists. This actually looks to me like a notation of an interval.

Comment: Agree with arkascha: it more looks like the prescription of the for loop. A real example loop would probably look like `for (1 : 10) { dosomething(); }`.

Answer (score -1):

It is a short hand for-loop, I dont think your example is an actual example so:

If we talk java and make som changes it would look something like this:

```
List<String> somelist = // fill up a list with some strings

//Itterates through the list and prints out each string
for (String value : somelist) { //Get string from list and set it to variable string
  System.out.println(value); 
}
```

in PHP it would look something like this:

```
$somelist = array( fill array with strings );

//Itterates through the array and prints out each string
foreach ($somelist as $value){
 echo $value;
}
```